# Get the name of the file a link points to in c

Tags: c, linux, shell

Iḿ writing a function which must return at the end the name of the file the link is pointing to if you enter -link and not return it if you dont write that command. The thing is that I dont know how to get the name of the file with the function "readlink()" because it returns the size of the file but not the name, and searching in "https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/readlink.html" I couldnt understand the way to get the name from the file.

```
printf("%s   %ld (%lu)  %s  %s ", time, info.st_nlink, info.st_ino, pw->pw_name, gr->gr_name); //prints a bunch of information about the file
 printf( (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
 printf( (info.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
 if(!opts.link){ //If the -link command wasnt written
      printf("    %ld %s\n", info.st_size, tokens[2]);
 } else{
    //Here I need to print the same as in the last line but adding the name of the file the link points to like this: 
    printf("    %ld %s -> %s\n", info.st_size, tokens[2], name);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the POSIX `readlink` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html):

> The `readlink()` function shall place the contents of the symbolic link referred to by `path` in the buffer `buf`...

You pass the link name in the first argument (named `path` in the reference). The function will then expand the link and copy it into the second argument (named `buf`). The size of the array used for `buf` is passed as the third argument (`bufsize`).

The function returns the length of the byte array it wrote in `buf` (it is *not* a string except by accident). Or `-1` on error.

You you could call it something like:

```
char buffer[1024];
ssize_t link_string_length;
if ((link_string_length = readlink(your_filename_for_stat, buffer, sizeof buffer)) == -1)
{
    perror("readlink");
}
else
{
    // Make sure that the buffer is terminated as a string
    buffer[link_string_length] = '\0';

    printf("%s -> %s\n", your_filename_for_stat, buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`readlink()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html).  The return value is the length of the name, but one of the arguments is a buffer into which the name is copied:

```
ssize_t readlink(const char *restrict path, char *restrict buf,
       size_t bufsize);
```

Beware that the name is not null-terminated:

> The `readlink()` function shall place the contents of the symbolic link referred to by path in the buffer *buf* which has size *bufsize*. If the number of bytes in the symbolic link is less than *bufsize*, the contents of the remainder of buf are unspecified. If the *buf* argument is not large enough to contain the link content, the first *bufsize* bytes shall be placed in *buf*.

You should ensure that there's enough space in the buffer for the return value plus a null byte.

My opinion on the design of `readlink()` not adding the null byte to create a string is NSFW.