# Get the file that is calling the current executable through a symbolic link

Tags: c, linux, symlink

In a Linux system, I'm trying to write a C program `source.c` which can behave differently according to the caller through a symbolic link. It compiles into an executable file `source`, and there are multiple files linked to it:

`ln -s source link1`

`ln -s source link2`

I want to make `source` output differently when I call `link1` vs `link2`, but I can't find a way to recognize, in `source.c`, the filename of the caller.

I've read the [readlink solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69616020/get-the-name-of-the-file-a-link-points-to-in-c), but it only returns the `source`.

Comment: *It compiles into an executable file source* Off-topic, but bad idea to have an identical name to a shell builtin. A simple and less opaque thing to do would be just to have scripts with those names, passing the appropriate parameters and invoking `notsource` ;)

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `argv[0]`?  Or have I missed the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, `argv[0]` will contain the name used to invoke the program.  You can use this to see which symlink it was called with.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if (!strcmp(argv[0], "link1") {
       // do actions for link1
   } else if (!strcmp(argv[0], "link2") {
       // do actions for link2
   } else {
       printf("invoked as unknown name: %s\n", argv[0]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```